# Fetch and forward consent-string as an amp-ad vendor

Tags: amp-html, amp-ad

We developed an AMP integration through  tag some time ago.

```
<amp-ad
  width="320"
  height="50"
  type="smartadserver"
  data-site="94612"
  data-page="629154"
  data-format="38952"
  data-domain="https://<YourSmartAdServerDomain>"
>
</amp-ad>
```

Now I would like to support the GDPR consent-string and include this GDPR compliant consent-string in my adcall.
So I want my  tag to fetch the consent-string (that has been generated by a GDPR and AMP-compliant CMP).

I was looking for some documentation. First, I checked a AMP compliant CMP (https://developers.didomi.io/cmp/amp) but there is no info about how a vendor should retrieve the consent-string in an AMP environment.
Then I searched in https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/extensions/amp-consent/amp-consent.md#checkconsenthref and more specifically in https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/tree/master/ads#amp-consent-integration but I did not find any concrete sample of how I should implement the consent-string in my ad tag ...

Does anyone know how to forward a consent-string for such integration? I would like to send it like in any other regular integration, where the adcall forwards the URL parameter `gdpr_consent=<VALUE OF THE CONSENT STRING>`

Thanks!